# MSG_PEEK misbehavior with socket read/recv

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have been trying to debug a problem that seems to pop up when I am using MSG_PEEK

I have a socket accept() which then uses a loop on recv() to get the first few bytes of the stream, but uses MSG_PEEK in the recv() so that the  original buffer is unchanged.

All of the other socket operations I am using are using read/write instead of recv/send. Does this cause a problem? It seems to me like the only difference is whether the MSG_PEEK flag is used on the first recv right after the accept.

Comment: Debug what problem? The only difference what? What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

Mixing `send()` / `recv()` with `write()` / `read()` on a socket is fine.  You haven't given enough information to even speculate wildly on what your actual problem is.